# How to fix the bubbling and discoloration here on cement walls?

Tags: walls, cement

we have some paint on cement blocks in the basement, with some staining and a little bubbling in some areas. The black stains I can just paint and it will look better I’m sure but what about the areas where the paint has bubbled a little bit? I was told this was efflorescence when we had an inspection done and that no water was there presently, so assuming water intrusion no longer an issue what is the proper fix for us here?

Thank you

Comment: Water intrusion can come and go, maybe years in between.  The proper fix is to make sure the outside of the walls are sealed or need resealing.  For the paint, just clean(maybe sand) and remove all loose paint(all bubbled paint).  Test the black stains for mold, unless known not mold.